# Visual Studio: edit-and-continue on handled exceptions?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

Here's a code reproducing the behavior I'm expecting to get:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // try // #2
        {
            string x = null; // #1
            AssertNotNull(x, nameof(x));
        }
        // catch (ArgumentNullException) { } // #2
        Console.WriteLine("Passed.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    public static void AssertNotNull<T>(T arg, string argName) where T : class
    {
        if (arg == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(argName);
    }
```

The behavior is the same for any VS starting from VS2008 (did not check on earlier versions).

If you run it under debug (using a standard debugging settings) you're not allowed to continue until you fix the code (using the EnC). Hitting F5 will just rerun assertion due to `[DebuggerHidden]` and "Unwind stack on unhandled exception" setting combo (setting is enabled by default).

To fix the code, just replace the #1 line with `object x = ""`, set the next statement to it and hit F5 again.

Now, enable "break when thrown" for the ArgumentNullException and uncomment the lines marked with #2.
The behavior changes: you're stopped on assertion again, but the stack does not unwind (easy to check with CallStack window). F5 will continue from the place the exception was thrown.

Ok, so... now the question is:
Is there any way to enable auto stack unwinding when breaking on **handled** exceptions?

Hidden VS option, existing extension or (maybe) API that can be used from my own extension?

**UPD:** To clarify the question:  I want to break at the line with failed assertion, edit the code with edit and continue, set next statement to the fixed code and continue the execution.

As it works if the exception is not caught down the stack.

**UPD2** As proposed by Hans Passant: Posted [an suggestion on UserVoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/13293105-edit-and-continue-should-work-for-handled-exceptio). Feel free to vote:)

Comment: The stack just isn't unwound yet when you use "break when thrown".  Simply keep single-stepping until you're back into the Main method.

Comment: @HansPassant "break when thrown on handled" does not prevent you from continuing the execution. 
Just run the sample (as it is) under debugger - it will break you again and again until you fix the code.
I want to get the same behavior for handled exceptions too (ideally, only for the ones being thrown from assertion methods, but any way will work).

Comment: I know, that's why single-stepping works.  Your snippet doesn't give me any trouble to step past the catch block and use SetNext.  Pretty unclear why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: I think what you're searching for is how to make the 'Break When Thrown' in combination with `[DebuggerHidden]`

Comment: @Snake, actually no. The DebuggerHidden just forces debugger to break on the line with assertion, not inside the assertion method itself. The trouble part is what happens next. In case the exception is __unhandled__ the stack is unwound automatically, In case it is not the stack does not unwind and you had to unwind it by hand to enable EnC (and in some cases it fails to unwind with 0x80004005 error).

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you want to catch your exception and when you catch it you want to throw it again??? Or you want to print your stack and continiu the program... What is the result that you want to get exaclty?

Comment: @Otkachenio thanks for asking, updated the question to clarify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> and uncomment the lines marked with #2

This is the critical part of your question.  You changed more than one thing, the critical change is that you altered the way the stack is unwound.  The debugger option you like is titled "Unwind stack **on unhandled exception**".  Problem is, there is no unhandled exception anymore.  Your catch clause handles it and it is now the CLR that unwinds the stack.

And it must be the CLR that does the unwinding, the debugger does not have an option to do it on the first-chance exception break that you asked for.  And SetNext can't work at that point.  Which, if I interpret the question correctly, you would really like to have since what you need to do next is busy work, single stepping through the catch block is not enormous joy.

Although it is not implemented, I *think* it is technically do-able.  But only because I'm blissfully unaware how much work the debugger team will have to do.  It is a good ask to make E+C work better, you can [propose it here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015).  Post the URL to your proposal as a commnent and good odds it will get a bunch of votes.  I'll vote for it.

Comment: >you can propose it here
Thanks for the idea, done (see upd2 in the question).

Answer (score 2):

> To clarify the question: I want to break at the line with failed
>   assertion, edit the code with edit and continue, set next statement to
>   the fixed code and continue the execution.

1. Open the "Exception Settings" Menu (Debug > Windows > Exception Settings)
2. Under "Common Language Runtime Exceptions", check the box for "System.ArgumentNullException". (Or check them all, whatever you're looking for.)

It should now break whenever a `System.ArgumentNullException` is thrown, regardless if it will be caught in a `catch` block.

However, [you cannot edit and continue active statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164927.aspx). If you try to modify your assertion line, you'll see something like this:

[image]