# How to Edit and Continue out of of a Catch block?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2022, edit-and-continue

I recently reinstalled Windows and VS 2022 along with it. Now I can't get all of my old Edit and Continue functions working.

Specifically, being able to Edit and Continue out of a Catch block - it is working fine otherwise. I am getting the "Unable to set the next statement. The attempt to unwind the callstack failed" error when I try to Set Next Statement after an edit.

Previously I would hit a Catch, make a change to the code, Set Next Statement and be on my merry way. The trick was I *had* to make a change, if I just Set Next Statement to rerun a section of code, I got an error (I do not recall what the error was.) It was not the slickest workflow - but it worked really well for this particularly unique legacy VB.Net project I am constantly fussing with (long story, just roll with it!)

Any idea what voodoo magic settings I need to reenable this?

Comment: Maybe try the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32455046/unable-to-set-next-statement-when-debugging I think it has to do with [how the call stack was unwound](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36358560/6530134).  What is the exception you are capturing?

Comment: @SSS you have to do some simple voodoo to enable it, and it has some limitations, but it is an immense productivity booster if you use it right!

Comment: @TimothyG. I had cleared all CLR exceptions per a suggestion I saw. I tried renabling NullReferenceException and ArgumentNullException, but no joy. I agree it seems like a problem with stack unwinding, and I disabled JIT as was suggested I found to help in this. The "Unwind stack on unhandled exception" option is no longer available, but that does not make sense as the exception is handled.

Comment: I found a sort of workaround. If I add a Finally to the Try block and just put a Debug.Print("") in there, I can step out of the catch block (which unwinds the frame) and then I can Set Next Statement and continue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the 'answer' I can not add comments yet - not enough rep points.

Have you tried putting a try block in the for loop?

```
For x = 0 to Whatever
  Try
    doSomething
  Catch Ex As Exception
    DoSomethingElse
  Finally
  ' this gets executed whatever, error or not
  End Try
Next x`
```

Comment: There is no loop.

Comment: I was confused then, you mentioned …” next statement” …  Which is part of the for-next statement.  I did include the 'finally' in my code which solves the problem.